# How to extract date from text in excel such as VBR021617?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that lists tags such as,

```
Tag
VBR021617
VBR031218
VBR010119
```

I would like to create a new column that takes out the dates. Expected result below:

```
Date
2/16/2017
3/12/2018
01/01/2019
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do your regional settings use mm/dd/yyyy date order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(2000+RIGHT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2),MID(A1,6,2))
```

and copy downward.  Then apply proper formatting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! Brilliant

Comment: What if the the text has a leading 4 character instead of 3? 
For example VRBB021617? Trying to understand the formula.

Comment: oh! I got it :)               =DATE(2000+RIGHT(B3,2),MID(B3,5,2),MID(B3,7,2))

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution but this should work:

```
=MID(A1,4,2)&"/"&MID(A1,6,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

[image: img1]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following.

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1;4;2);"/";MID(A1;6;2);"/";MID(A1;8;2))
```

where A1 holds a value such as VBR021617, etc.